# Nested unordered list toggle using jQuery and add or edit node on list

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a problem toggling nested html in unordered lists. I'm using the code below.
It toggles the whole `div` not the `li` items inside it, please help me...
I want to create a tree view using an html unordered list and be able to create and edit every created child node. I want my output to look like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/7JPf6/2/).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    ListOfCategoryEquipment();

    function ListOfCategoryEquipment() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Handler/CommonHandler.ashx",
                data: "MethodName=GetCategoryEquipmentList",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (json) {
                    debugger;
                    CallBackCategoryEquipment(json);

                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert('Sorry,There was an Problem');
                },
                complete: function (xhr, status) {
                    // alert("Requst Complete");
                }

            }
        );



     function CallBackCategoryEquipment(data) {

            var html = '<ul>';

            for (var n in data) { // Each top-level entry

                html += '<li>' + data[n].Title + '<ol>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data[n].ChildCategoryList.length; i++) { // Each sub-entry
                    html += "<li>" + data[n].ChildCategoryList[i].Title + "<button id='testid' type='button' >Test</button>" + "</li>";
                }
                html += '</ol></li>';

            }
            html += '</ul>';
            $('#ListOfCategoryEquipment').append(html);

        }

    });

 $('#ListOfCategoryEquipment').click(function () {
 $('ol').first().toggle('slow');

 });
```

html:

```
<div id="ListOfCategoryEquipment" style="width:400px; margin-left:100px; border:thin solid red; background-color: #ddd;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a need for external container which could hold both the complete sub menu

so i have changed the code like this

**HTML CODE:**

`<ul>
    <div>
        <li>1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>`

**JQUERY CODE:**

`$("li").on('click',function () {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});`

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7JPf6/78/

Happy Coding:)

Comment: i will try it thanks for seggestions...in our code how we can change it any idea

Comment: @AsifIslam: in `CallBackCategoryEquipment()` where the sub menu`s are constructed, just enclose it within a div like i have done above.liek this  ` html += '<div><li>' + data[n].Title + '<ol>';` and at the closing end `html += '</ol></li></div>';`. is through that the final dom will look like above.

Comment: i have try it  html output same that is required us but $("li").click(function () { $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle(); }); click event not fired...

Comment: Could you post the final html dom structure thats generated , so that i can check where is the issue